# How do you determine the Windows Server version of a Domain Controller, from a computer on the server?

Tags: active-directory, windows-7-x64, domaincontroller

I'm using Windows 7 Enterprise at my job.

I am trying to determine which version of Windows Server is used on the Domain Controller. 
I have already used gpresult /r and have not been able to determine which server version it is.

Whois also yielded no usable results.

I cannot access the ADUC using this computer, as I'm not admin, and just trying to figure out.

Learning Network+ in the future.

Comment: What if there is more than one Domain Controller? Do you just want the version of any Domain Controller?

Comment: I want the version of Windows ran by the domain controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following command:

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $computer | Select-Object csname, caption, csdversion
```